# HTML to XML parser in java to parse a section of HTML

Tags: java, html, xml, html-parsing

I want to parse certain section of the html to XML.

```
<div class="superviewer">text</div>
  <p>-----content----<p>
  <p>-----content----<p>
  <p>-----content----<p>

<div class="superviewer">text</div>
   <p>-----content----<p>
  <p>-----content----<p>
<div class="superviewer">text</div>
   <p>-----content----<p>
</div>
<div class="superviewer">text</div>
```

Required output:

```
<superviewer>
   <content>
    <p>----content----</p>
    <p>----content----</p>
    <p>----content----</p>
   </content>
</superuser>

<superviewer>
  <content>
    <p>----content----</p>
    <p>----content----</p>
   </content>
</superuser>

<superviewer>
  <content>
    <p>----content----</p>
  </content>
</superuser>

<superviewer>
  <content>
  </content>
</superuser>
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("filename"));        
    Elements superUserInfos = doc.getElementsByClass("superviewer");        
    for(Element superUserInfo:superUserInfos){
        String info=superUserInfo.text();
        Elements siblings = superUserInfo.siblingElements();
        List<Element> elementsBetween = new ArrayList<Element>();
        for (Element sibling:siblings) {
          if ((! "div".equals(sibling.tagName())))
            elementsBetween.add(sibling);
            break;
        }
        if (! elementsBetween.isEmpty()){
          processElementsBetween(elementsBetween);
        elementsBetween.clear();
        }
    }
```

Please suggest how I can do it and I tried using **Jsoup** but I am not able to get the contents in correct format.In each **superviewer** all the contents are showing.

Comment: Generally, HTML is not XML so can not be parsed by xslt processors, like in your case `<p>-----content----<p>` would need a terminating `</p>`. With xhtml you might succeed.

Comment: I am trying to convert to xml using JSOUP then again formatting according to XSTL

Comment: ok then I did not understand correctly, can you show (edit question) what you're doing with jsoup to possibly identify the problem with the "all contents showing in each supterviewer"?